# Install cx_Oracle for Python

Tags: python, oracle

Am on Debian 5, I've been trying to install cx_oracle module for python without any success. First, I installed oracle-xe-client and its dependency (followed tutorial in the following link [here](http://le-gall.net/pierrick/blog/index.php/2006/09/21/80-how-to-use-ubuntu-linux-as-an-oracle-client)).

Then, I used the scripts in **/usr/lib/oracle/xe/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/client/bin** to populate environment variables such as PATH, ORACLE_HOME and NLS_LANG.

Once, this was completed, I tried to run:

```
sudo easy_install cx_oracle
```

But I keep getting the following error:

```
Searching for cx-oracle
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/cx_oracle/
Reading http://cx-oracle.sourceforge.net
Reading http://starship.python.net/crew/atuining
Best match: cx-Oracle 5.0.4
Downloading http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/cx-oracle/cx_Oracle-5.0.4.tar.gz?download
Processing cx_Oracle-5.0.4.tar.gz
Running cx_Oracle-5.0.4/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-xsylvG/cx_Oracle-5.0.4/egg-dist-tmp-8KoqIx
error: cannot locate an Oracle software installation
```

Any idea what I missed here?

Comment: What does `echo $ORACLE_HOME` output?

Comment: $ORACLE_HOME is set for /usr/lib/oracle/xe/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/client

Comment: When in doubt, read the official [cx_Oracle Installation instructions](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html) which contain up to date information than in many of the answers in this post.

Comment: The latest version of cx_Oracle, (renamed to python-oracledb) doesn't need the Instant Client mentioned in various answers, and thus obsoletes them.  See the new [installation instructions](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I recommend that you grab the rpm files and install them with alien. That way, you can later on run `apt-get purge no-longer-needed`.

[In my case](http://tshepang.net/accessing-oracle-db-using-python-in-debian), the only env variable I needed is `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, so I did:

```
echo export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client/lib >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

I suppose in your case that path variable will be `/usr/lib/oracle/xe/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/client/lib`.

Comment: Instant Client 19 RPMs will configure and run `ldconfig` so you don't need to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Answer (score 76):

The alternate way, that doesn't require RPMs. You need to be `root`.

1. **Dependencies**

   Install the following packages:

   ```
   apt-get install python-dev build-essential libaio1
   ```
2. **Download *Instant Client for Linux x86-64***

   Download the following files from Oracle's [download site](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-097480.html):

   [image: files preview]
3. **Extract the zip files**

   Unzip the downloaded zip files to some directory, I'm using:

   ```
   /opt/ora/
   ```
4. **Add environment variables**

   Create a file in `/etc/profile.d/oracle.sh` that includes

   ```
   export ORACLE_HOME=/opt/ora/instantclient_11_2
   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$ORACLE_HOME
   ```

   Create a file in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle.conf` that includes

   ```
   /opt/ora/instantclient_11_2
   ```

   Execute the following command

   ```
   sudo ldconfig
   ```

   *Note: you may need to reboot to apply settings*
5. **Create a symlink**

   ```
   cd $ORACLE_HOME 
   ln -s libclntsh.so.11.1 libclntsh.so
   ```
6. **Install `cx_Oracle` python package**

   - You may install using `pip`

     ```
     pip install cx_Oracle
     ```
   - Or install manually

     Download the [cx_Oracle source zip](http://cx-oracle.sourceforge.net/) that corresponds with your Python and Oracle version. Then expand the archive, and run from the extracted directory:

     ```
     python setup.py build 
     python setup.py install
     ```

Comment: This might be off topic as the I am building it on Mac OS X 10.9.2 and finally got it working. Other than Burhan's tips on 1-7 to set environment variables for the build paths and the symlinks, it appears that Oracle's dylib files has *hardcoded* link paths!!! So this article helps a bit: http://caseymorford.com/2014/04/17/installing-oci8-with-mamp-pro/ for TL;DR, you need to create another two symlinks to resolve the dlopen() errors. Otherwise we are good!

Comment: I did steps 1-5 on Ubuntu 16.2 (Docker) and all worked!!! Thanks! Saved so much time...

Comment: Don't set ORACLE_HOME with Instant Client - it can cause the wrong configuration files to be read at runtime.  Old cx_Oracle installs needed it at _build_ time when compiling, but that's no longer the case.  Also, new Instant Clients automatically create sym links, so that step can be omitted.  In summary, just follow the [cx_Oracle installation instructions](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html#installing-cx-oracle-on-linux).

Answer (score 5):

The following worked for me, both on mac and Linux. This one command should download needed additional files, without need need to set environment variables.

```
python -m pip install cx_Oracle --pre
```

Note, the **--pre** option is for development and pre-release of the Oracle driver. As of this posting, it was grabbing `cx_Oracle-6.0rc1.tar.gz`, which was needed. (I'm using python 3.6)

Answer (score 4):

Thx Burhan Khalid, I overlooked your "You need to be root" quote, but found the way when you are not the root [here](http://python.6.x6.nabble.com/cx-oracle-module-problems-td1741977.html).

At point 7 you need to use:

```
sudo env ORACLE_HOME=$ORACLE_HOME python setup.py install
```

Or

```
sudo env ORACLE_HOME=/path/to/instantclient python setup.py install
```

Answer (score 3):

Thanks Burhan Khalid. Your advice to make a a soft link make my installation finally work.

To recap:

1. You need both the basic version and the SDK version of instant client
2. You need to set both LD_LIBRARY_PATH and ORACLE_HOME
3. You need to create a soft link (ln -s libclntsh.so.12.1 libclntsh.so in my    case)

None of this is documented anywhere, which is quite unbelievable and quite frustrating. I spent over 3 hours yesterday with failed builds because I didn't know to create a soft link.

Answer (score 2):

I think it may be the sudo has no access to get ORACLE_HOME.You can do like this.

> sudo visudo

modify the text add

> Defaults env_keep += "ORACLE_HOME"

then

> sudo python setup.py build install

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can install the cx_Oracle module without the PIP using the following steps

1. Download the source from here https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cx_Oracle
   [cx_Oracle-6.1.tar.gz ]
2. Extract the tar using the following commands (Linux)

   gunzip cx_Oracle-6.1.tar.gz

   tar -xf cx_Oracle-6.1.tar
3. `cd cx_Oracle-6.1`
4. Build the module

   python setup.py build
5. Install the module

   python setup.py install

Comment: can it be executed by a regular user or do you need admin privileges to build and install it (on linux)?

Answer (score 1):

This just worked for me on **Ubuntu 16**:
Download ('instantclient-basic-linux.x64-12.2.0.1.0.zip' and 'instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-12.2.0.1.0.zip') from Oracle web site and then do following script (you can do piece by piece and I did as a ROOT):

```
apt-get install -y python-dev build-essential libaio1
mkdir -p /opt/ora/
cd /opt/ora/

## Now put 2 ZIP files:
# ('instantclient-basic-linux.x64-12.2.0.1.0.zip' and 'instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-12.2.0.1.0.zip') 
# into /opt/ora/ and unzip them -> both will be unzipped into 1 directory: /opt/ora/instantclient_12_2 

rm -rf /etc/profile.d/oracle.sh
echo "export ORACLE_HOME=/opt/ora/instantclient_12_2"  >> /etc/profile.d/oracle.sh
echo "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$ORACLE_HOME"  >> /etc/profile.d/oracle.sh
chmod 777 /etc/profile.d/oracle.sh
source /etc/profile.d/oracle.sh
env | grep -i ora  # This will check current ENVIRONMENT settings for Oracle


rm -rf /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle.conf
echo "/opt/ora/instantclient_12_2" >> /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle.conf
ldconfig
cd $ORACLE_HOME  
ls -lrth libclntsh*   # This will show which version of 'libclntsh' you have... --> needed for following line:

ln -s libclntsh.so.12.1 libclntsh.so

pip install cx_Oracle   # Maybe not needed but I did it anyway (only pip install cx_Oracle without above steps did not work for me...)
```

Your python scripts are now ready to use 'cx_Oracle'... Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
python -m pip install cx_Oracle --upgrade
```

For details refer to the oracle quick start guide

https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#quick-start-cx-oracle-installation

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to install in MAC , just  unzip the Oracle client which you downloaded and place it into the folder where you written python scripts.
it will start working.

There is too much problem of setting up environmental variables. 
It worked for me.

Hope this helps.

Thanks

Comment: You don't set any environment variables on macOS - not since Apple's SIP stopped DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH working.  From the [Instant Client installation instructions](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/intel-macsoft-096467.html#ic_osx_inst) you just run `mkdir ~/lib;  ln -s ~/instantclient_18_1/libclntsh.dylib ~/lib/`

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall it with the following code:

```
!pip install --proxy http://username:windowspwd@10.200.72.2:8080 --upgrade --force-reinstall cx_Oracle
```

Answer (score 0):

If you require to install a specific version of cx_Oracle, like 7.3 which was the last version with support for Python 2, you can do the following:

```
python -m pip install cx_Oracle==7.3
```